# GraphQL + Relay + Graphene

Tags: graphql, relay, graphene-python

```
class Product(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, id, context, info):
        #must implement to relay
        pass


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    product = graphene.Field(Product, id=graphene.String())
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    def resolve_product(self, args, context, info):
        session =  context['session']
        id_ = from_global_id(args['id'])[1]
        p = session.query(ProductModel).filter(ProductModel.id == id_).first()
        return p
```

I am trying to use GraphQL + Relay + Grephene. But I am a little bit confused. Can I support both queries using relay? Or when implementing realy I will only support the second one?

Do I always need to translate the globalId to database primary key?

Graph QL:

```
{
    product (id: "XYZ"){
       id
       title
    }
}
```

Relay:

```
{
        node(id: "XYZ") {
          id
          ... on product {
            title
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Relay spec and implementation **requires** you to support a `node` query  in addition you your query root (usually `viewer`)

Relay will use `node` internally when it needs to fetch fields for a specific node.
Regardless of node, if you really want a `product` query and call it yourself from one of your Relay Containers.

As for global ids, yes - you always need to translate from global id to primary key.
But to be more exact - you always need to translate from global ID to the internal key representation of whatever DB behind the ObjectType you're querying.
The global id contains the type information - which ObjectType we're trying to fetch. Without that information the framework wouldn't know what ObjectType to send the id to so it can do the fetching.